# Roslyn CSharpSyntaxRewriter to modify multiple class files and generate the build without source code modification

Tags: c#, syntax, compiler-construction, aop, roslyn

I am trying implement AOP in C#. Though I understand, I have to use Roslyn CSharpSyntaxRewriter but I do not get how I can plug it in the compilation process to modify multiple class files and generate the build. I do not want to modify the source files only the compiled code should contain my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn doesn't have any built-in support for extending the compilation process like this; at best you can use it to write your own files to disk and extend the build process via MSBuild, but that's *not* easy to get right.